# Is it correct to say "it is not that far a distance"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say: "it is not that far a distance"?

Comment: What is the question here — word order, choice of adjective, something else, all of the above? Please clarify. Questions of the form "are there any mistakes in this text" are expressly off-topic. Please clearly state what you think the mistake might be, why you think so, and which alternatives you have considered. Then the question can be reopened. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's correct, but "not that *great* a distance" would be more common.

Comment: Yes. See this [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+a+distance%2Cgreat+a+distance%2Clong+a+distance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). But ["not so/that/as far to X"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+so+far+to%2Cnot+as+far+to%2Cnot+all+that+far+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) would be more natural.

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatical, but why would you want to say it? Wouldn't you say *It's not far*?

Comment: Well, OP might mean "It's not **all that** far" :-)